# compress level of python gzip module not working

Tags: python, gzip

I was trying to write data into a compressed file using the python gzip module. But the module does not seem to accept the level of compression

I followed the syntax specified in the official Python documentation on [gzip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html)

Here is a sample snippet of code, please correct me if I am wrong

```
import gzip
fd = gzip.GzipFile(filename = "temp", mode = "w", compresslevel = 6)
fd.write("some text")
```

When I run the file command on the file temp I always get the output as "max compression" even though it is not in this case

```
file temp 
temp: gzip compressed data, was "temp", last modified: Tue Jul 30 23:12:29 2013, max compression
```

Comment: bugfix patch here: https://bugs.python.org/issue27521  - should enter python3 soon :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`some text` is too small to test. Try with big string.

I tried it with a big text file, and it works as expected.

```
import gzip
import os

with open('/path/to/big-file', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()

for level in range(10):
    with gzip.GzipFile(filename='temp', mode='w', compresslevel=level) as f:
        f.write(content)
    print('level={}, size={}'.format(level, os.path.getsize('temp')))
```

Above code produce following output:

```
level=0, size=56564
level=1, size=21150
level=2, size=20635
level=3, size=20291
level=4, size=19260
level=5, size=18818
level=6, size=18721
level=7, size=18713
level=8, size=18700
level=9, size=18702
```

Comment: +1.  It's likely that the `gzip` module is simply not writing the compression level to the header or similar, but as that block of code is largely outputting magic values I'm not sure where this is done.

Comment: Shouldn't the for-loop be indented under the first `with` so that content is within scope?

Comment: @nueverest, `content` is available outside the `with` statement. I did it in purpose to close the file as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata may be incorrect, but compression level setting does work correctly.

```
dhruv@dhruv:/tmp$ python z.py <-- level 6
dhruv@dhruv:/tmp$ ll temp 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhruv dhruv 215903 Jul 30 23:36 temp
dhruv@dhruv:/tmp$ fg
emacs -nw z.py
dhruv@dhruv:/tmp$ python z.py  <--- level 9 
dhruv@dhruv:/tmp$ ll temp 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dhruv dhruv 215723 Jul 30 23:36 temp
```

Contents of z.py:

```
import gzip
fd = gzip.GzipFile(filename = "temp", mode = "w", compresslevel = 9)
for i in range(0,100000):
    fd.write(str(i))
```